# Get index position tag

Tags: java, jsoup

How i can get index position element in String?(don't count tag)

```
 String html = "<title>Hello</title>"
                + "<p>World</p><p>123</p>";
```

> Position **title** :0(because first)
>
> Position **/title** :5(because after Hello(lenght = 5))
>
> Position **p** :5
>
> Position **/p** :10(because after Hello(lenght = 5)+World(lenght = 5))
>
> Position next **p** :10
>
> Position next **/p**:13(because after Hello(lenght = 5)+World(lenght = 5) +123(lenght = 5)

How to create it?

Comment: There's no easy way to do this with Jsoup. Tell us more why you need this so maybe there's other way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Krystian G , i take string with Html(p,background-color,color,table,img) . I need to read string spell and apply to each letter own style if it is. I want to write index html . And when i read string  I check the index .

Comment: @Krystian I could only do this:
https://gist.github.com/heavywar/f683c1689039f72adc56888674d033e7 . I know that's bullshit . But it  works :)))